# How to add multiple pages to single page navigation bar in dotCMS

Tags: content-management-system, dotcms

I created two individual pages - a "home" and a "product" page. I want to add these to a page navigation bar. So, this page should contain a navigation bar and two menu elements named "HOME" and "PRODUCT".

How can I achieve this using dotCMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page properties, check the box "show on menu" for both your pages.  Then you can use the navigation tool ($navtool) to build your navigation.  See this page in the documentation:

http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/NavigationTool